# Apache + php-fpm configuration profiles(pools) for vhosts

Tags: apache, configuration, threadpool, fastcgi, php

I just switched from (apache + mpm_prefork) to (apache + php-fpm +mod_fastcgi) using references from

[Switching from prefork MPM to worker MPM + php-fpm on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290568/switching-from-prefork-mpm-to-worker-mpm-php-fpm-on-ubuntu)
http://www.garron.me/en/blog/ubuntu-lamp-apache2-mpm-worker-and-php-fpm.html

Previously main apache configuration was in

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and vhost configuration was in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/example1.com
/etc/apache2/sites-available/example2.com
/etc/apache2/sites-available/example3.com
/etc/apache2/sites-available/examplen.com
```

After switching to php-fpm I need to make configuration profile (pool) like
1. high.conf which should be default with setting like **max_execution_time , memory_limit and other are set to high**. (It is for drupal commerce websites)
2. light.conf with lower setting value for light weight normal website.

Is it possible to create **just two** profiles(pools) like this and assign these pools to multiple sites at once.?
can I delete above mentioned old vhost configuration file or shall i have to specify pool related settings in it?

**Update:** This is on VPS with standard user/group like root,www-data etc. and not for configuring shared hosting with multiple user/group.

**Update 2**: after further reading i tried something which might work pls correct me.
copied default www.conf

```
cp /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/light.conf

sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/light.conf
```

replace php5-fpm.sock  with php5-fpm-light.sock and made changes to pm.* setting to lower values like

```
pm.max_children = 20 ;default www.conf value pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 2 ;default www.conf value pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 2;default www.conf value pm.min_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_spare_servers = 4;default www.conf value pm.max_spare_servers = 6
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M ;default www.conf value php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 192M
```

All light weight vhost files are configured to fastcgi with php5-fpm-light.sock and all other drupal commerce sites are configred to fastcgi with php5-fpm.sock
like

```
#light weight
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-light -socket  /var/run/php5-fpm-light.sock -idle-timeout 30 -pass-header Authorization

#drupal commerce -idle-time-out is set to high.
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket  /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 250 -pass-header Authorization
```

When tried to restart using

```
service apache2 restart && service php5-fpm restart
```

error is generating

*FastCgiExternalServer: redefinition of previously defined class "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-light"*.

1. For the above error is it means seperate pools should be created
   with same settings but with different socket?
2. If yes, shouldn't it increase the memory consumption due to
   php_admin_value[memory_limit]?
3. will -idle-timeout parameter overrides max_execution_time of php.ini or they are both different settings?

The main thing about this apache+php-fpm+fastcgi for me is that there are several config files like following where i couldn't figure out which settings overrides(applied) at the end.

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/php5-fpm.conf
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf
/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf (might be master process config)
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf (might be more if multiple pools are present)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the same "redefinition of previously defined class" issue, and the solution was to make sure all *filename* components (such as you `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi`) are unique, including among all virtual hosts.

That doesn't necessarily mean you need distinct sockets/ports, but if you intend to run a separate PHP-FPM process for each virtual host running as a separate user, perhaps also using Apache's suExec function, then you will need to specify distinct sockets/ports in separate pools, and add the corresponding value to each `VirtualHost` block in Apache config.